# Installing ruby gems Error: operation nor permitted - usr/bin/sprockets

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Im trying to get rubymine to work but i always keep getting this error "operation not permitted"

```
Gabriellas-MBP:~ GabriellaKampe$ gem install rails
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 directory.
Gabriellas-MBP:~ GabriellaKampe$  sudo gem install rails
Password:
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EPERM)
    Operation not permitted - /usr/bin/sprockets
Gabriellas-MBP:~ GabriellaKampe$
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have permission to write to the gemfile directory of your the ruby version that comes bundled with your OS. What you'll have to do is manage your ruby versions using either `rbenv` or `rvm`. I will recommend `rbenv` and you can follow the guide on these links [rbenv rails install Mac OS](https://gorails.com/setup/osx/10.11-el-capitan) or [rbenv rails install Ubuntu](https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/14.04)